# Tag synonym request: [export] and [exporting]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/export) x 3572

> "Export" refers to the automated or semi-automated conversion of data sets from one data format to another. The term refers to both act of exporting and to the result of the action, i.e. the exported data set.

[exporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exporting) x 194

> *No wiki entry*